# Is users socket id a critical information? (security point of view)

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I'm using [socket.io](http://socket.io/) to build a chat application. Is it ok if clients receive the socket id of their interlocutors in terms of security? Can the client do something with this information? My assumption is no as only the server can emit message to other clients but I'm new to Websocket mechanism so I'm not fully aware of all possibilities.

Comment: I don't see why it would be a security concern, although I also don't see why it's necessary for a client to receive the socket ids of all the other clients, either.  Is this happening due to some fundamental aspect of the `Websocket` API, or because your server is deliberately sending the info?  In the latter case, why are you sending it/what does the client do with the info?  Are you using socket ids as stand-ins for proper user-ids?

Comment: The socket id is not directly sent but it is used to form a unique string that is the room name and this string is passed to clients (so a malicious person could understand that the room name contains socket ids).
Also regarding your last question would it be a bad practice to use the socket id directly as user id? (provided that the lifetime of a user is only the lifetime of the session)

Comment: @Absurdev: Well, if those rooms are supposed to be private and there is no other authentication the prevents joining a private room than to know its name, then yes it would be a bad idea to use public ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.id` is just a string identifier for the socket object that can be used internally by the server or can be shared with other clients as a "handle" for that user.  A client can't do anything with sockets that the server doesn't specifically support a command for (other than connect/disconnect).

So whether it matters if the id is a secret depends entirely on what server actions you support and what arguments they take.  By default, there's nothing a client can do with the id.  So, unless your server supports a command that takes an id and your design expects the id to be a secret, then there should be no issue.